# PHP - Array Returns Empty with Value Provided

Tags: php

I am trying to access an array key dynamically with the codes below.

```
$order_detail = new OrderDetail((int) $params['id_order_detail']);
$products = $order_detail->getList($id_order);

$test = $products[$order_detail->id]['unit_price_tax_incl'];
```

$order_detail->id is returning just fine and $products is an array which I have var_dump below:

**$products var_dump:**

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( 
[id_order_detail] => 54676 
[id_order] => 17733 
[unit_price_tax_incl] => 5.900000 
)
..... more results .....
```

Unfortunately, I am unable to retrieve ['unit_price_tax_incl'] as it is returning empty currently. Is there anything that I am missing? Baffled.

Any guide is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: what is the value of `$order_detail->id` ?

Comment: The value is [id_order_detail]..... Am I accessing it wrongly?

Comment: for accessing your sample data in `$test = $products[$order_detail->id]['unit_price_tax_incl'];` value of `$order_detail->id` should be 0

Comment: in your `$test` variable it will use `$order_detail->id` as an index. So for example your `$order_detail->id = 1` it will only fetch the array with keys of `unit_price_tax_incl` that has an `index of 1`

Comment: Yes, @jerome. That is what I am trying to achieve.. but I am unable to retrieve [unit_price_tax_incl] => 5.900000.....

Comment: Have you ever check your `order_detail->id` value ? it should be `0` if you want to access `5.900000` because thats the index of the array.

Comment: ah, that's a good start for me. it's not, it is 54676 cos I am taking as id_order_detail. $order_detail->id does not return as 0

Comment: @Enthu well thats the reason its not fetching cause its finding the `54676` index of your array that may not exist / may exist but it has different value

Comment: Yes, I admit that is a silly mistake I overlooked. It's a dynamic solution I am creating, missed this part... took hours and now I have realised with better pair of eyes from you guys. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you obtain a list so you should access  eg for the firts row elements

```
  $test = $products[0]['unit_price_tax_incl'];
```

be sure that  your `$order_detail->id` contani a proper value for the list access

Comment: I am trying to access the [unit_price_tax_incl] => 5.900000 by providing $order_detail->id

Comment: i don't understand you comment  .. if you wnat access using $order_detail->id  then  this value must match for the index  in $products  .. check for the content of order_detail->id .  If the content is 0  then ypu get the first row value for unit_price_tax_incl

Comment: Yes, I think that's is the grave mistake I did. I will check my codes again.

Answer (score 0):

if `$order_detail->id` is exist in `$products` array you will get the result otherwise it will throw the error..Use [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) to check the key exist in the array or not.Try below

```
if(array_key_exists($order_detail->id,$products)){
    $test = $products[$order_detail->id]['unit_price_tax_incl'];
}else{
    $test = '';
    //order_detail id doest not exist in the products array
}
```

Comment: Did you check my answer? @Enthu